# API Google Map - Fallo en el renderizado de librerías

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

Me encuentro migrando de servidor un proyecto desarrollado con Wordpress y que utiliza la API de Google Maps.
Resulta que no hubo problemas en levantarlo en local, en un entorno de desarrollo y otro de QA. Pero al momento de levantarlo en un entorno de Homologación (HML) se presenta un problema en el front-end con los archivos JS que renderiza la API de Google.

Pueden observar el proyecto en su actual servidor (que no es mio) en el siguiente enlace: https://mapa.thedigitalhub.com.ar/es/

El problema que presenta el entorno de HML (se encuentra en una intranet) es que al hacer el hover en los barrios del mapa no se dibujan los polígonos ni nada. Me di cuenta que la API renderiza nueve o diez archivos JS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que observo en el entorno de HML es que hay dos de estos archivos faltantes. Los que se llaman geometry.js y poly.js. Claramente, entre ambos construyen los polígonos del mapa y es lo que falla. Yo no desarrollé el proyecto, solo lo estoy migrando de servidor.

Por lo que entiendo del proyecto. Se hace la llamada a un endpoint de Google que hace que se renderizen todos los archivos necesarios. Pero faltan esos.

Realmente ya no sé qué hacer. ¿En dónde se encuentran estas dos librerías? ¿Por qué no las está renderizando? :(

Ideas ???

Muchas Gracias !

**EDITO:**

**Solución: Había que setear en ON la variable "allow_url_fopen" en el php.ini. Eso es todo.**

Comment: ¿Qué errores te muestra en la consola?

Comment: No se muestran nada en consola. Gracias !

Comment: Según lo que vi en ese sitio web, todo funciona bien, se dibuja el mapa, los barrios, los puntos, al seleccionar un barrio, me redirecciona al detalle con otro mapa y puedo navegar entre los puntos. Estoy usando Mozilla Firefox 71. (toca actualizar ahora)

Comment: Exactamente, ese funciona bien. Pero lo estoy migrando de servidor. En este momento estamos levantando un nuevo entorno y nos encontramos con este problema que ya no sabemos qué hacer. El entorno que estamos levantando está en una intranet. Solo puedo decirles que esos dos archivos de la api no están.

Comment: Momento, esa intranet, ¿tiene acceso a internet?

Comment: En teoría no ya que quienes manejan los servidores no permiten que esa VM lo tenga. Me excede. Pero lo extraño es que teniéndolo o no, hay archivos que si se renderizan y estos dos que no.

Comment: Si no hay acceso a internet, entonces, es muy probable que lo necesario para la comunicación de las librerías de Gmaps con el backend de Google se encuentre roto.

Comment: Le dimos acceso total a internet a la VM. Sigue sin funcionar. Me quedé sin ideas.

Comment: ¿Hay algún firewall?

Comment: Ahí ya desconozco el entorno qué contiene, pero lo chequeo.

Comment: Si antes funcionaba y ahora dejó de funcionar. Pueden ser varias razones, inclusive ver si hay alguna limitación de las peticiones en la API (la parte donde hay para establecer un dominio)